# python -m SimpleHTTPServer gives syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.6, simplehttpserver, python-webbrowser

(New to Python)

I've downloaded a project from Github which contains an index.html file. When I bring the file to my web browser I get some errors that tell me I can't run js libraries.

In the Python shell, I'm trying to setup the HTTPSimpleServer using this command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

but I get this error:

```
File "<stdn>", line 1
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm running Python 3.6.

I've also tried with

```
python3 -m http.server
```

and it produces the same error.

Am I missing a library? Don't see any syntax issues.

Comment: You run it in your system shell (bash/zsh), not python shell

Comment: I configured the commandprompt (cmd) to run with Python code using the approach here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXqTw5eO0Mw. Cmd responds to the command "python" which makes me assume that Python code is now working in my system shell. When I run the command "python -m SimpleHTTPServer", I get the same error as before.

Comment: After running `python`, do you run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in cmd prompt (`C:\>`) or python interpreter (`>>>`)?

Comment: In the cmd prompt. I type "python" and then "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" in the following line.

Comment: Is C:/Python/Scripts in your system path?

Comment: Yes, I added it as well.

Comment: Based on `File "<stdn>", line 1` in the error message, I believe you're running the command in python interpreter, and not in cmd prompt. Can you confirm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173205/discussion-between-saud-and-sudhanshu-vishnoi).

Answer (score 0):

You need to type

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

at your command prompt, not inside the python interpreter.  That is a python error message and the line above is a command line for your OS.